# QGIS import OpenAIP

Tags: qgis, import

I have files from OpenAIP (http://www.openaip.net).

How can I import them ?

Format available are : .aip .cup .dat

.aip is xml file.

For point :

```
<OPENAIP VERSION="960678" DATAFORMAT="1.1">
<WAYPOINTS>
<AIRPORT TYPE="HELI_CIVIL">
  <COUNTRY>BE</COUNTRY>
  <NAME>AALST</NAME>
  <ICAO>EBAL</ICAO>
  <GEOLOCATION>
    <LAT>50.943</LAT>
    <LON>4.056</LON>
    <ELEV UNIT="M">42.9768</ELEV>
  </GEOLOCATION>
</AIRPORT>
```

There is also for Aera :

```
<OPENAIP VERSION="86085ce18c01559e0d7146af93e0ca5502382bb5" DATAFORMAT="1.1">
<AIRSPACES>
<ASP CATEGORY="CTR">
  <VERSION>fa328804a8e2c808ab25c3918a8ea13f58be77e1</VERSION>
  <ID>40185</ID>
  <COUNTRY>BE</COUNTRY>
  <NAME>ANTWERP CTR 135.200</NAME>
  <ALTLIMIT_TOP REFERENCE="MSL">
    <ALT UNIT="F">2500</ALT>
  </ALTLIMIT_TOP>
  <ALTLIMIT_BOTTOM REFERENCE="GND">
    <ALT UNIT="F">0</ALT>
  </ALTLIMIT_BOTTOM>
  <GEOMETRY>
    <POLYGON>4.2666666666667 51.268333333333, 4.6269444444444 51.268333333333, 4.7961111111111 51.168055555556, 4.3125 51.075555555556, 4.3004490803605 51.081168749361, 4.2890673204322 51.087310195178, 4.278401321455 51.093940203165, 4.2685043313859 51.101025872012, 4.2594258493449 51.108532023644, 4.2512113769306 51.11642137487, 4.243902187728 51.124654719655, 4.2375351162181 51.133191121174, 4.2321423672384 51.14198811276, 4.227751347071 51.151001906823, 4.2243845171567 51.16018761074, 4.2220592713486 51.169499448721, 4.2207878375243 51.178890988563, 4.2205772042746 51.188315372208, 4.2214290732744 51.197725548991, 4.2233398378284 51.207074510408, 4.226300587955 51.216315525255, 4.2302971422425 51.225402373947, 4.2353101065724 51.234289580836, 4.2413149596623 51.242932643324, 4.2482821652295 51.251288256611, 4.2561773104272 51.259314532887, 4.2649612700477 51.266971213813, 4.2666666666667 51.268333333333</POLYGON>
  </GEOMETRY>
</ASP>
```

QGIS version 2.10 / Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

You can use this tool https://github.com/openAIP/airspace-converter to convert the airspace data to openAIR format. QGIS is able to import data in openAIR format.

If you only need data for a specific country, contact me. I can give you access to the shapefiles for the particular country.

openAIP version 2 will also provide shapefiles.